When I run my code in react it's not run or not loading on chrome what is the reason behind this
PS C:\Users\Pankaj gupta\Desktop\React.js\textutils> npm run
Lifecycle scripts included in textutils@0.1.0:
start
react-scripts start
test
react-scripts test
available via npm run-script:
build
react-scripts build
eject
react-scripts eject
I run the code with Command npm run
But code is not running and not reload the output on chrome browser
I expect the correct output
